# Prove that \[(x^{2} +xy -y^{2})^{2}=1\] has consecutive Fibonacci numbers as solution

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Apologies if it's a duplicate question. I was not able to find such question though. I don't know how to proceed on this.

Comment: $x^2+xy-y^2=\pm 1$ can be a starting point.

Comment: Yes. and consecutive fibonacci numbers are the solutions to it. But how to prove it? How to solve a polynomial equation with two variables and only one equation is given?

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 3):

The hint.

Prove by induction that $$f_{n+1}^2-f_{n+1}f_n-f_n^2=(-1)^n.$$

Comment: @Ratul Sarkar I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks Mikchael. This is Cassini's identity. Learnt a beautiful thing today.

Comment: You are welcome,  @Ratul!